# How to connect switch to electric box containing 3 grey (twin and earth) cables?

Tags: switch, kitchens, refrigerator

The circuit breaker belonging to kitchen tripped today and I narrowed the problem down to faulty switch controlling my fridge.

I immediately removed the switch but I forgot to take picture of previous connection.

Please can someone help me with connecting new switch?

[image: Electric cable box with 3 grey ( sets of twin and earth) cables]

Comment: What type of switch (picture) and what else is without power  with the switch removed.

Comment: does this box house a switch only, or a switched outlet? are you in UK?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Why do you have a switch controlling your fridge outlet, of all things?!

Comment: In the US refrigerators are plugged into **outlets** and not on switches. Can confirm that you are taking about a switch?

Comment: Hello all, Thanks for your response. Sorry for the delay. What I meant was the switch controls a power outlet for connecting the  fridge. @Jasen yes, I'm based in Birmingham UK.

Comment: The box house contains only the switch. The power outlet is located a bit away from the switch.

Comment: @AGLakshmanan -- why do you even have the refrigerator on a switch to begin with?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Hmm.. I don't know. I am just novice DIYer trying to save some bucks and trying not to electrocute everyone in my household. Maybe Jasen or Simon B are more suited to explain the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greens go together. These are ground.
Blacks go together. These are neutral.
Reds go together, except one which is separated from the other reds by the switch.

Two of the reds will be live (or with the power off will measure as being already connected) these two are the ring main and they go together.

Judging by the layout in the box the two reds coming from the top are probably the ones that go together.

Comment: You are my new hero ! Yes, that fixed it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a standard UK ring circuit.  The chances are that the top two are two sides of the ring, and the bottom one is to the fridge.  It should be obvious if the fridge outlet is immediately below the switch.

So the two top reds go to the "in" L side of the switch.  The top two blacks go to the "in" N side of the switch.  The bottom red goes to the "out" L, the bottom black goes to the "out" N, and all the earths go to an earth terminal.

Comment: Bingo ! You are spot on sir. Thank you very much for your advice. I managed not to get everyone eloctrocuted :D.